# How to disable Event log message about adhoc error message when using RaisError?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-event-log

Some of the developers are using the following syntax in RaiseError:

```
RAISERROR('My business error message', 16, 0)
```

With the purpose of reusing the catch part of the try..catch block
for business error too.

But I spotted several event log entries like this:

```
Msg # 50006, <blabla> please register the error message with sp_addmessage
```

There's some way to disable the creation of such events? I searched google, msdn
and docs but didn't find a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means some other developers are using `RAISERROR(50006, 16,1)`... When the msgid syntax is used (or when the @local_variable in thesyntax is an int) the expectation is that the message was added to the local messages table. This is the normal approach for localized errors, to raiserror a msgid and add messages localized for various languages.

Whatever application/developer uses the msgid syntax, he/she is also responsible to add the message to the messages table during deployment, for the locale of the server.

Comment: HMmm... Interesting. I'll do some investigation..... And return to the SF to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

> RAISEERROR('This is just information',
>   10, 1)

This will tell SQL Server to raise a non fatal error.

Ref: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/handling-errors-in-stored-procedures